# Simple Panels question on where the panels get placed on the page

Tags: 7, panels

This is a silly question but how does Panels know where to insert the panels I just made? I didn't type a single line of PHP and yet there it is! It's like magic (woooh...)! On a side note, can I define where it gets placed through PHP? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Panels places the panel into the 'content' region of the selected page.

If you want to place it somewhere else on the page, try using mini-panels to create a block and place it that way.  No need to write custom PHP code for that.

Comment: Wait, since Panels is placed in the content region, then this basically makes most of the regions section of my theme's .info file obsolete. Am I right?

Comment: no - you can still place blocks through the blocks UI onto a page that uses panels.  the header and footer will stay intact, etc...

Comment: I see. So Panels searches for the content region by default. But you can still place panels via Mini Panels and existing Page Panels.